# Remove hard coded number of days in -mtime option to find files in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find files in a directory which are older than 30 days.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=/tmp
find /tmp -mtime +30 -type f
```

I want to know if there is a way to **NOT** hardcode the folder location and `-mtime +30` in my shell script but to manage them externally to avoid making any change in the script in future.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done indeed, using environment variables. Imagine you create two environment variables, let's say `ENV_FIND_STARTFOLDER` and `ENV_FIND_MODIFICATION_TIME`, then you can rewrite your command as:

```
find $ENV_FIND_STARTFOLDER -mtime +$ENV_FIND_MODIFICATION_TIME -type f
```

However, I'm urging you to be very cautious with this: environment variables are only defined in that one environment (if anybody ever asks you for your script and launches it on another machine which does not have those variables, it won't work), and also: if you start creating environment variables just for one script or even just one command, and you do this for all the scripts and commands you're about to create, you might create a very chaotic environment.

By the way, the fact that I have chosen such long names is already a way to handle this, as you can see:

```
ENV_FIND_STARTFOLDER
ENV_FIND_MODIFICATION_TIME

=> I have invented the "naming convention":
ENV  : it is an environment variable I have created
FIND : for which script/command is it to be used
STARTFOLDER, MODIFICATION_TIME : a very clear indication of its meaning
```

Comment: Hi @Dominique,
Thanks a lot for your answer with nice explanation. There was a lot to think.
However, I tried another way using simple $1 approach.

For example: I can replace +30 in the code with '$1' in find command and then 
`$ <script_name> +30` will help me choose the number of days whatever I want whenever I run the script manually. Is this recommended though?

Comment: The usage of input parameters is heavily advised above the usage of environment variables, I did not realise this was a possibility for you.